# Festival text-to-speech ignores `current-voice` defined in `.festivalrc` in 20.04

Tags: configuration, text-to-speech, festival, scheme

On Ubuntu 18.04 I had in my `~/.festivalrc`

```
(voice.select 'en1_embrola)
```

which works as expected.

However after upgrading to 20.04 my default voice is `kal_diphone`

On festival's interactive shell `(voice.select 'en1_embrola)` does the correct thing so I know that the embrola voice is properly installed.

I can also `(!set variable-name 'to-value)` in my `~/.festivalrc` and see that value in a fresh interactive shell, so I know my configuration file is evaluated.

However `current-voice` in a fresh interactive shell is always `kal_diphone`.

As a side note, I noticed that there is a difference between the values of `voice-locations` between my Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 installs:

On 18.04 it is:

```
((kal_diphone . "/usr/share/festival/voices/english/kal_diphone/")
 (en1_mbrola . "/usr/share/festival/voices/english/en1_mbrola/"))
```

while on 20.04 it has the reverse order:

```
((en1_mbrola . "/usr/share/festival/voices/english/en1_mbrola/")
 (kal_diphone . "/usr/share/festival/voices/english/kal_diphone/"))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my [hack](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235156) the proper solution is trivial:

The `~/.festivalrc` should be:

```
(set! voice_default 'voice_en1_embrola)
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is very much a hack**, and while it solves my immediate problem, I don't consider it a solution.

It is possible to override the call to `set_voice_default`, by (sudo) editing the `/usr/share/festival/voices.scm` file and adding the `(set! voice_default 'voice_en1_embrola)` near the bottom of that file like so:

```
--- a/usr/share/festival/voices.scm
+++ b/usr/share/festival/voices.scm
@@ -437,4 +437,5 @@


 (set_voice_default default-voice-priority-list)
+(set! voice_default 'voice_en1_embrola)
 (provide 'voices)
```